# Chart a map with highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter, r-devtools

I am trying to chart a map with highcharter using the hcmap function:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter)
hcmap("custom/south-america")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Installing tidyr
Downloading GitHub repo RcppCore/Rcpp@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/RcppCore/Rcpp/zipball/master
Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build Rcpp
> library(highcharter)
> library(Rcpp)
Warning message:
package ‘Rcpp’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
> hcmap("custom/south-america")
Error: could not find function "hcmap"
```

Comment: [related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096233/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build-dplyr#35099084)

Comment: Are you saying I need to "download and install a newer version of Command Line Tools as well as XCode" for me able to get the map from highcharter To be honest, after reading the posts you mention not sure how to proceed...

Comment: If you run the code line by line you'll notice the `devtools` part don't work, so what you _ask_ in not highcharter related. Try installing the package from CRAN `install.packages("highcharter")`