# Error when plotting sf object --- Error: could not find function "geom_sf"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently running R Version 3.3.3 on Windows and have ggplot2 version 2.2.1 and the sf package version 0.5-4 and am getting an error saying that R could not find the function "geom_sf."

I expected to find the function because it is listed in Tidyverse documentation at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html.

The output of `ls("package:ggplot2")` did not show "geom_sf" as an included function and I could not find it in the library files.

Does anyone know how I might get this elusive package?

Comment: haver you tried to update ggplot ?? which version of ggplot you have ? run following code `packageVersion('ggplot2')`

Comment: In my question I mentioned I have ggplot2 version 2.2.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While running R as the administrator, reinstall ggplot2 like this:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)
```

You should be able to see it now with ?geom_sf

For questions related to using devtools, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096233/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build-dplyr).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution worked perfectly. I didn't think to pull the package directly from the Tidyverse Github repo.

Comment: Same problem with R version 3.4 and I got `ERROR: dependency 'digest' is not available for package 'ggplot2'` with the above solution.

Comment: @user3673 I had to use `install_github()` for `digest` as well.