# Error: could not find function "geom_sf"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently running R version 3.4.2 on Windows and have ggplot2 (via tidyverse) and sf package versions 3.4.2. I'm attempting to map spatial data using the ggplot2 sf kit.

When trying to run geom_sf, I receive an error: `could not find function "geom_sf"`.

When I search the ggplot2 package using `ls("package:ggplot2")`, geom_sf is not listed in the library files.

I installed devtools and ran `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`. However, I receive an error: `Installation failed: Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.come port 443: Timed out`. I assume the firewall at work is halting this connection.

To get around this, I tried downloading the zip manually from https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2 and running `install.packages('ggplot2-master.zip', lib = 'C:/filepath')` and receive the error: `package 'ggplot2-master.zip' is not available (for R version 3.4.2)`. I was getting the same error before I updated from 3.4.1.

**TLDR**: I'm having the same issue as this user: [Error when plotting sf object --- Error: could not find function "geom_sf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185226/error-when-plotting-sf-object-error-could-not-find-function-geom-sf)
but the solution does not work for me.

*Does anyone see where I may be missing something? Or how to access this highly referenced (more streamlined) package?*

Comment: If you download the zipped package, you will need to follow the procedure for installing it from local source, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474081/903061). Use the arguments `repos = NULL, type = "source"` in `install.packages()`.

Comment: I don't think "source" would be the correct setting for a zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded from the URL you cited then the appropriate next step would be to execute this at the R session command line assuming your package is in the working directory:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', repo=NULL, lib = 'C:/filepath')
```

The `.zip` extension is implicit in trying to install from a binary windows file and you need to tell it NOT to attempt downloading from CRAN.