# Geom_sf not found - developer version of tidyverse does not fix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to use geom_sf with the most current developer version of tidyverse and R 3.5.0, and the function cannot be found.  This previous question ([Error when plotting sf object --- Error: could not find function "geom_sf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185226/error-when-plotting-sf-object-error-could-not-find-function-geom-sf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) was able to solve the issue with the developer version, but that is not he issue here.  Any ideas about why this is/how to fix it?

Comment: What version of ggplot2 does `sessionInfo()` say you have installed and loaded?

Comment: You might need to install `sf` package as well

Comment: @ Tung, sf_0.6-3 is installed and loaded.  Or do you mean that I might need the developer version?

Comment: @ MrFlick, your question helped me fix the issue.  The sessionInfo() let me know that only tidyverse was loaded in the developer version and not ggplot2.  I didn't realize that downloading the developer version of tidyverse is separate from downloading the developer version of individual packages within the tidyverse.  I'm a bit embarrassed that I didn't remember to check that before posting a question...

Answer (score 1):

The developer version of tidyverse does not download the developer version of ggplot2.  Downloading the developer version of ggplot2 solved the issue.