# Create a congressional district map of a state in R

Tags: r, google-maps, heatmap

I would like to create visual maps of congressional districts within R.
I would like to give it data on the number of people voting in each district and make a heat map by district as a visual via R.

Here are some generic examples of state maps divided by congressional district (without voting data or a heat map) but I would want to create a fairly minimalistic map to plot off of so these are similar in feel to what I want to create:

1. [Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_delegations_from_Texas)
2. [Minnesota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota%27s_congressional_districts)

Here is some sample code for a base map in R, outlining the congressional districts:

```
library(USAboundariesData) # Needed for us_congressional()
library(sf) # Needed for st_geometry()

mn_congressional <- us_congressional(states = "Minnesota", resolution = "high")
plot(st_geometry(mn_congressional))
```

However, I now want to incorporate this with a column of voting totals for each of the districts and color the district sections in this map as a heat map?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: see `USAboundaries::us_congressional(resolution = "high", states = c("Texas", "Minnesota"))`

Comment: @Mako212 I updated my question including your suggestion to get the blank layout for the state.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you'd like to incorporate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is pretty easy to add data to.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(USAboundaries)

cd_mn <- USAboundaries::us_congressional(resolution = "high", states = c("Minnesota"))
cd_mn$Voters <- runif(length(cd_mn$geometry), 500, 5000) #create some random data for the number of districts

ggplot(cd_mn) + geom_sf(aes(fill = Voters)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(heat.colors(5)))
```

[image]

Comment: And for OP to match his/her data to the map, they need to match by the district number in the `cd115fp` column.

Comment: Is there a different package for `geom_sf`? I am getting an error: `could not find function "geom_sf"`

Comment: It should be in `ggplot2`, but see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185226/error-when-plotting-sf-object-error-could-not-find-function-geom-sf) solves it. I am using `ggplot2` version 3.0.0.

Comment: It was a version issue on my end, updated and code now runs.